# listview scrolling top can't set index 0 of

Tags: android, listview

when scroll to and I click item  list to set the fist index it is not set .what ?

```
public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1, int index, long arg3) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub  

        //ImageView imgNew = (ImageView) arg1.findViewById(R.id.imgIcon);

        //imgNew.setImageResource(R.drawable.push);


        ImageView imgOld = (ImageView) listView1.getChildAt(0).findViewById(R.id.imgIcon);
        imgOld.setImageResource(R.drawable.push);

}
```

Answer (score 0):

If I'm not mistaken, you're trying to change an image once it's been clicked. Try doing something like this:

```
    ImageView imgOld = (ImageView) listView1.getChildAt(index).findViewById(R.id.imgIcon);
```

Answer (score 0):

If you have free time and want to save your time (in the future), watch [Google I/O 2010 - The world of ListView](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=wDBM6wVEO70) (about 1 hour).

When I started to code in Android, I spent lots of time on this stackoverflow with `ListView`. Then someone pointed me to that video, and it was be easier :-)

Answer (score 0):

I don't understand the issue but just in case

> getChildAt(0)

0 index means first **visible** item on the **screen**